# Install Toad for current user and to specific directory

Tags: sql-server, toad

Is there anyway i can Install Toad for SQL Server to specific directory and for current user?

I could not find any option from the installation guide from command prompt which they have provided.

```
>msiexec /i /qb+ ToadDataPointViewer-3.7.2.16.msi
```

By Default it tries to install to Program Files for which the current user dont's have permission. And it also tries to install for all users that is also an access issue. So i want to install to my user home directory and only for my user.

Any help would appreciate. Thanks

Comment: I might be wrong, but: you don't have access to "Program files". Apparently, you don't have permission to install anything, but found a way to do it via operating system command prompt. So my question is: are you **sure** you want to do that? Why wouldn't you ask the administrator to install it for you, if it is legal? I, somehow, don't like the idea of bypassing restrictions which are enforced for a reason. Imagine: what if they catch you having that software? As I said: I may be wrong, and - if that's so - I apologize. And no, I don't know the answer to your question.

Comment: @Littlefoot I dont have write access to programfiles however the Toad software which i am trying to install is freewear, If it's good than will request for official installation. Installing standard freewear software like toad notepad java shouldnt be an issue i believe.

Comment: I agree, but I think that you should ask your admin to allow you doing that. Don't look for workarounds (I explained why).